# Install VirtualBox Headless only

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, headless

I want to install VirtualBox on a fresh debian box without having to install an X-Server.

How can that be done ?

Answer (score 4):

VirtualBox (both OSE as well as the free binary version) can be installed without X.

when running VMs you can run the VirtualBox X client over X11 although its not much fun unless you have a really fast network, but you can start your VMs headless using VBoxHeadless and then connect to them over the network via VRDP to get a console (useful for installations) or just using SSH.

VirtualBox is very good about that - everything you want to do can be managed using command line tools, even feeding keyboard input.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a Debian box right this moment, but I just checked on an Ubuntu box, and the dependencies for the virtualbox-ose package do not seem to include X.  They do include several libraries for X.

So my first stab at an answer for you is to simply try: `apt-get install virtualbox-ose`

Here is a guide with lots of help for managing a headless VirtualBox:

http://www.howtoforge.com/vboxheadless-running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-2.0-on-a-headless-ubuntu-8.04-server

If you have trouble doing what you want with VirtualBox you might also look into other virtualization systems such as Xen.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

yes, also phpvirtualbox is what you can use for managing them.

with it, installing client will become much easier and you can do in-browser remote desktop.

1. for debian box, you will firstly install some packages via apt-get

   apt-get install libaudio2 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libllvm2.9 libmng1 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libxmu6 libxxf86vm1 qdbus
2. install lamp server
3. install phpvirtualbox by download and extraction
4. add a vbox user and create /etc/default/virtualbox  http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/wiki/vboxwebServiceConfigLinux
5. edit vbox config.php file, (username and pass)

You will proabably also install virtualbox extension pack by example:

```
VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.8-75467.vbox-extpack
```

After that, start all the service or do a reboot! Any questions, commet below