# Installing and utilizing VirtualBox on a headless CentOS machine

Tags: centos, virtualbox, headless

In follow-up to a question about [Debian](https://serverfault.com/q/69412/2321), how can VirtualBox be installed to a headless CentOS machine, and then utilized on that headless machine?

Comment: I found this - http://www.howtoforge.com/vboxheadless-running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-2.0-on-a-headless-ubuntu-8.04-server - but it's only for Ubuntu :|

Comment: Any reason you can't use, say, KVM or Xen?

Comment: @Shane Madden - in this specific case, the headless machine is in a backup data center with no physical access, so I'd like to use something that isn't *quite* as low-level as KVM .. plus, we're already using VirtualBox for testing on local machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install the VirtualBox package onto the headless machine like you would any other one (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). Afterwards, VirtualBox can be controlled via the `vboxmanage` command, documented in detail on http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html . In order to set up your VMs easily (with graphical OS setup and so on), I recommend, however, to create and install them in a graphical environment and then copy the hard disk images to your headless machine.